# How I can run 2 commands simultaneously in package.json scripts using npm start?

Tags: npm, less, package.json, httpserver

When I'm using npm start command, only first command is starting, whatever command is first in the line (less or httpserver).
I'm using Windows 10 64.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "less-watch-compiler & httpserver -p 8888"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "less": "*",
    "less-watch-compiler": "*",
    "httpserver": "*"
  }
```

$npm start

> @ start E:\work\pattern-library
>   less-watch-compiler & httpserver -p 8888

Config file E:\work\pattern-library\less-watch-compiler.config.json is loaded.
Watching a directory for file changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use two `&` symbols:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "less-watch-compiler && httpserver -p 8888"
  }
```

This will start both scripts sequentially.